# Sveltekit bwip-js QRCode

Tags: yarnpkg, sveltekit, bwip-js

Its probably a newbie problem (Not understanding what is difference between, nodejs, browser and react code). I am using bwipjs-js to generate QR code in my sveltekit app. I am using bwipjs (toCanvas(...) method) in my `myqr.ts` file.

It works fine and generates the QR codes. But running

`yarn unit.test` generates the below error.

```
Property 'toCanvas' does not exist on type 'typeof BwipJs'.

    1190     bwipjs.toCanvas(tempCanvas, qrOptions);
```

`yarn unit-test` must pass in order for the code to go into production.

I have tried importing the bwip-js in different ways as under:

```
// import bwipjs from 'bwip-js';
import * as bwipjs from 'bwip-js';
// import { gs1_128 } from 'bwip-js';
```

code used to generate the QR:

```
    let tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    try {
        bwipjs.toCanvas(tempCanvas, qrOptions);
        // const generateQR = async () => (await gs1_128(qrOptions));
        // qrImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', generateQR());    
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error creating QR.', extract400Error(e));
    }
```

If I use the third option import `{ gs1_128 } from 'bwip-js';` then the error is not thrown while running the test but an error is raised while running the code (in other words it doesnot run / generate QR codes).

I can see in the [bwip-js documentation](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js#react-usage) for react usage there is this toCanvas method used.

I am not sure how to fix the issue. Which version should I use here (node, browser, react, Browser ES6)? I actually have no clue what is going on here.

I can see that toCanvas(...) method is present in the file `'node_modules/bwip-js/dist/bwip-js.d.ts,'`.

Many thanks for explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that

```
    import * as bwipjs from 'bwip-js';
```

looks into bwip-js's `package.json` and imports different files for the typescript compiler and the generated javascript code, respectively: the compiler compiles against `bwip-js-node.d.ts`, which for some reason does not contain the `toCanvas` function, while the compiled code contains `bwip-js.d.ts`, which has this function.

As long as the bwip-js author does not fix it, the following workaround worked for me:

```
    import * as bwipjs from 'bwip-js';
    ...
    (bwipjs as any).toCanvas(...);
```

Comment: shall try and if it works will mark it as accepted answer. I have another solution to it. Will post that as well.